# Ajax call seems to fail in firefox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, firefox

I am currently working on a project where I sent out data from a JavaScript to PHP script using an Ajax call. I tried to look for an answer on Stackoverflow, but not success therefor I made a question.

This code is working properly on my chrome browser, but it fails when I try it out in Firefox or Safari.

```js
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "index.php?option=com_lowbudgetrestvisual&task=sdc.connect&format=json",
  cache: false,
  data: {
    data: data
  },
  success: function(data, http, state) {},
  error: function(http, state, error) {
    console.log("Response -> failed");
    console.log("http : " + http);
    console.log("state: " + state);
    console.log("error: " + error);
  }
});
```

**EDIT:** whenever i tried console log in `google chrome`, is just says `Response -> success`. 
When i tried logging in firefox I get the following text.

`Response -> failed
http = [object Object]
state = error
error =`

**EDIT 2:** I am making a `form` and then submitting it to `PHP script` to save it in the `database` using PHP. Another `ajax` call is in the form making sure that an email is send out to the user in the form and an admin. How i made sure both worked is by the following javascript code:

```
    $('#sdc').on("click", function(e) {

        e.preventDefault(); 

   {{ then some codes and the ajax call }}

    });

    $('#sdc').on("click", function() {
        $("#userForm").submit(); 
    });
```

**EDIT 3:** I tried the `console.log("http : " , http);` and this is what I get in console:

```js
    http = Object {
      readyState: 0,
      getResponseHeader: .ajax / v.getResponseHeader(),
      getAllResponseHeaders: .ajax / v.getAllResponseHeaders(),
      setRequestHeader: .ajax / v.setRequestHeader(),
      overrideMimeType: .ajax / v.overrideMimeType(),
      statusCode: .ajax / v.statusCode(),
      abort: .ajax / v.abort(),
      state: .Deferred / d.state(),
      always: .Deferred / d.always(),
      then: .Deferred / d.then(),
      11 more…
    }
```

Comment: is there any errors in the console ?

Comment: Check the console for errors in the request

Comment: have you checked your browser console, what type of error you are getting in mozilla?

Comment: see edit: console is just printing out what i asked for, without any errors.. But the network gives me a status code of 200 and 303

Comment: try comma instead of + which loads the toString version instead of showing the object content `console.log("http : ", http);`

Comment: try console.log("http", http); because chorme shows the object directly but firefox as type when add +.

Comment: Thankyou for the tip. See edit3 for the outcome!

Comment: Now the same for error and state?

Comment: may i know why you passing query parameter separately as you can already have post request where you can wrap  all passable  data in post request.

Comment: @mplungjan I did and the same log came out, only the object gave some details.

Comment: @Prajwal I don't understand what you mean. wrap all passable data in my post request?

Comment: change URL `url: "index.php?option=com_lowbudgetrestvisual&task=sdc.connect&format=json"`  to `url: index.php` and rest parameter pass it along with data value as `data: {
    data: data, option:com_lowbudgetrestvisual,task, sdc.connect,format=json
  }`


Also can you show what variable 'data' contains?

Comment: Oh i do that in the url, because the the joomla website needs that to redirect to the correct php script.

Comment: In de data are some variable like: name, address, date and so on.. they are not NULL! they can be successfully fetched in the php script whenever i test it out in chrome

Answer (score 0):

this code is working fine for me in firefox. Please check firefox browser version and jquery also. Please check also server php file path.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "test1.php",
  cache: false,
  data: {
    data: 'test'
  },
  success: function(data, http, state) {},
  error: function(http, state, error) {
    console.log("Response -> failed");
  }
});

</script>
```

Comment: It works in chrome. But updating firefox? Will this ajax request not work in older version of firefox?

Comment: not sure but my browser version is 49.0.1. It is working fine for me. Please check jquery also. I think it is your machine problem. or test in another machine.

Comment: You're right, my browser is 48, but now i'm afraid to deploy this project live.. what if the firefox users don't use the latest browser.. then my code basically won't work.

Comment: please check my code in your local host in test folder if this works. If this works then your live site code is not okay or not getting actual response. Please check servers side php file path

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124628/discussion-between-madankundu-and-hoffie).

Comment: I tried your code and it logged out "Response -> failed"

Comment: have you added sever php path as test1.php with just echo 'test'?